# When is Mirror.Child label nil?

Tags: swift, reflection, mirror

Documentation for `Mirror.Child` states,

> When the label component in not nil, it may represent the name of a stored property or an active enum case. If you pass strings to the descendant(*:*:) method, labels are used for lookup.

When is `Mirror.Child` `label` value nil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mirror.Child` can represent unlabelled values, hence `label` being `Optional`.

If you create a `Mirror` reflecting a type with named properties (such as a `struct` or `class`), `label` will have a non-nil value for each property. However, you can `Mirror` things with unnamed children as well, such as an `Array`.

When you `Mirror` an `Array`, the elements of the `Array` will be accessible as `Mirror.Child`, but their `label`s will be `nil`.

```
func mirrorChildren<T>(of object: T) {
    for child in Mirror(reflecting: object).children {
        print("Label: \(child.label ?? "nil"), value: \(child.value)")
    }
}

mirrorChildren(of: [1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
Label: nil, value: 1
Label: nil, value: 2
Label: nil, value: 3
```